# Python writing to a file - English converted to Chinese

Tags: python, encoding, file-writing

I open a file in python.

I read it in and process it (separate it into single words).

I write it to an output file.

The below picture shows my code, the shell (where I'm printing out each word before appending it to the file), and the output.

Why does it become Chinese characters? The encoding of the file is ANSI.

Edit: I should add that the output file seems to be encoded with UCS-2 LE BOM.

[image: Picture of code, shell, and output]

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize


with open('ALLSentences.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    text = myfile.read()

tokenized = word_tokenize(text)

file = open("output.txt", "a")
for word in tokenized:
    print(word)
    file.write(word + "\n")

file.close()
```

Comment: Update the post with code as text not an image, so that it will be more easy to read

Comment: Sorry yes, done!

Comment: Are you sure Notepad isn't the problem here? Could you try opening it from a terminal/powershell? `cd directory/where/file/is/stored` and then `type file.name`

Comment: That returns loads of boxes with question marks in them

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that Notepad is reading the file as if it is written in UTF-16, whereas you've written it in UTF8 (with only English characters).  That means Notepad is reading 16 bits at a time, and treating them as a single (chinese) unicode character.  Not sure if the fix is going to be at the notepad or Python end.

Comment: It would be really helpful to get the actual contents of the file, the equivalent of the output of `od -tx1` (we only need the first 16 bytes or so).

Comment: Choose the correct encoding when you open the file in notepad.

Comment: I tried to rerun it to generate the output again but now it's working fine? I think I may have changed the encoding in notepad++